# Push array into array then encode - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to combine a few mySQL queries in a single PHP and push it all into a single JSON object.

So, I'm starting with the first query...like this:

```
$data=[];

$response = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$final_count = count($response);
$data['count'] = $final_count;
```

If I then do `echo json_encode($data);` I get a nicely formatted object like: `{"count":61}`

I then have a second query that I put the results through a loop, like so:

```
$response = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$items = array();
foreach ($response as &$value) {
    $items[] = $value['date_added'];
}
echo json_encode($items);
```

And I get my nice set of dates:

```
["2017-06-24 00:08:58","2017-06-26 15:01:48","2017-06-27 15:01:48","2017-06-28 23:19:41","2017-06-29 01:38:07","2017-06-30 00:08:58"]
```

Here's the question, how do I get this all back together like so:

```
{
    "count": 61,
    "dates": [
        "2017-06-24 00:08:58",
        "2017-06-26 15:01:48",
        "2017-06-27 15:01:48",
        "2017-06-28 23:19:41",
        "2017-06-29 01:38:07",
        "2017-06-30 00:08:58"
    ]
}
```

Comment: use `array_merge` then encode :)

Comment: Just put the entries into the same array, currently you use two separate arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
 $myData['count'] = $final_count;
 $myData['dates'] = $items
 echo json_encode($myData);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$data=[];

$response = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$final_count = count($response);
// first store count in `$data`
$data['count'] = $final_count;

$data['dates'] = [];
$response = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// next, store dates in subarray of `$data`
foreach ($response as &$value) {
    $data['dates'][] = $value['date_added'];
}

// finally encode everything
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. The subarray thing is what I was missing...didn't even know that was a thing. : )

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can use array_merge of all your collected data.

Or:

```
$data=[];
// get $final_count
$data['count'] = $final_count;
// ... do some more stuff
// load items from db
$data['dates'] = $items;

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Well, that was simple...wasn't it. Thanks!

Comment: But I wasn't fast enough.